# @JsonView does not filter fields

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, json-deserialization

I have problem while deserializing JSON to Java Object. I have models and views as shown below:

```
public class View {
    public static class CreateIpSuccessResponse {}
    public static class CreateIpErrorResponse {}
}
```

I use this views in this classes:

Root class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CreateIpResponse {
    @JsonProperty(value = "pResponseCode")
    @JsonView({View.CreateIpSuccessResponse.class, View.CreateIpErrorResponse.class})
    private Object pResponseCode;
    @JsonProperty(value = "pResponse")
    @JsonView({View.CreateIpSuccessResponse.class, View.CreateIpErrorResponse.class})
    private CreateIpPResponse createIpPResponse;
}
```

First subclass:

```
@Data
public class CreateIpPResponse {
    @JsonProperty("Status")
    @JsonView({View.CreateIpSuccessResponse.class, View.CreateIpErrorResponse.class})
    private String status;
    @JsonProperty("Result")
    @JsonView({View.CreateIpSuccessResponse.class, View.CreateIpErrorResponse.class})
    private CreateIpResult result;
    @JsonProperty("responseCode")
    @JsonView({View.CreateIpSuccessResponse.class, View.CreateIpErrorResponse.class})
    private String responseCode;
}
```

Second subclass:

```
@Data
public class CreateIpResult {
    @JsonProperty(value = "partyid")
    @JsonView(View.CreateIpSuccessResponse.class)
    private String partyId;

    @JsonProperty(value = "Error")
    @JsonView(View.CreateIpErrorResponse.class)
    private String error;
}
```

Example of my json deserialization:

```
    public CreateIpResponse createIp(CreateIpRequest createIpRequest) throws IOException, SQLException {
        String pRequest = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(createIpRequest);
        Map<String, Object> response = openAccountRepository.callProcedure(pRequest, "createClientIP");
        BigDecimal responseCode = (BigDecimal) response.get("pResponseCode");
        if (responseCode.equals(new BigDecimal("200"))) {
            return mapper
                    .readerWithView(View.CreateIpSuccessResponse.class)
                    .forType(CreateIpResponse.class)
                    .readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(response));
        } else {
            return mapper
                    .readerWithView(View.CreateIpErrorResponse.class)
                    .forType(CreateIpResponse.class)
                    .readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(response));
        }
    }
```

When I deserialize ***CreateIpSuccessResponse*** view, I expect:

```
{
    "pResponseCode": 200,
    "pResponse": {
        "Status": "OK",
        "Result": {
            "partyid": "98493305"
        },
        "responseCode": "200"
    }
}
```

But I get:

```
{
    "pResponseCode": 200,
    "pResponse": {
        "Status": "OK",
        "Result": {
            "partyid": "98493305",
            "Error": null
        },
        "responseCode": "200"
    }
}
```

and vice versa, when I deserialize ***CreateIpErrorResponse*** view, I expect:

```
{
    "pResponseCode": 400,
    "pResponse": {
        "Status": "Error",
        "Result": {
            "Error": "Некорректная дата выпуска"
        },
        "responseCode": "200"
    }
}
```

But I get:

```
{
    "pResponseCode": 400,
    "pResponse": {
        "Status": "Error",
        "Result": {
            "partyid": null,
            "Error": "Некорректная дата выпуска"
        },
        "responseCode": "200"
    }
}
```

My question is why i don`t getting result that i need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that ObjectMapper is not ignoring null values when serializing objects. So when creating he object mapper use the setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL) method call to tell the ObjectMapper to ignore the null values:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
```

You can find the details [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-null-fields)

Edit: added the summarization of the solution as [moken](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13664137/moken) suggested in comments.

Comment: You should summarise what information a link provides as links to external sites can break